# Multy-layer xmlElements

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Let's assume that I have this class and I want to generate XML file using JAXB

```
 public class Document{

    private String id;
    private Date signatureDate;

    here goes Constructor, getters and setters
}
```

When I generate XML file I get something like this

```
`<document>
    <id>id3</id>
    <signatureDate>1970-01-01T01:00:00+01:00</signatureDate>
</documento>`
```

Now I want to wrap each attribute of the class with more elements: e.g. to indicate the type of the attributes.

```
`<document>
    <id>
        <paperid>
            <string>id3<string>
        <paperid>
    <id>
    <signatureDate>
        <signatureYearDayAndHour>
             <date>1970-01-01T01:00:00+01:00</date>
        </signatureYearDayAndHour>
    </signatureDate>
</documento>`
```

The final objective has to wrap each attribute of the class with different xmlElement.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried XmlElementWrapper but it seems to me that that works only with a group of elements.

Comment: Post the code you have tried so far; showing the output. This will help others to identify your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can use JAXB to apply custom meta-mapping rules like yours. JAXB defines it's own concrete XML/POJO mapping rules and only supports Java type, namespace, and other relatively simple customizing discussed in the official docs for the `bindings.xjb` file and the `xjc` tool.

What you can do, though, is to set up your XML parsing pipeline to apply filtering before the XML events get to JAXB unmarshalling. This is how you'd wire your custom filter in JAXP:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Document.class);
XMLFilter filter = new MyFilter();
SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
filter.setParent(sp.getXMLReader());
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
UnmarshallerHandler unmarshallerHandler =
  unmarshaller.getUnmarshallerHandler();
filter.setContentHandler(unmarshallerHandler);
filter.parse(inputsource);
```

This is how a generic filter implementation could look like (note this is just acting as identity filter; I've left implementing your custom mapping rules as an exercise :)

```
class MyFilter extends XMLFilterImpl {

  @Override
  public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts)
  throws SAXException {
    super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, atts);
  }

  @Override
  public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
  throws SAXException {
    super.endElement(uri, localName,  qName);
  }
}
```

To give you an idea about what's possible with filters, see eg. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forum/html/topic?id=60ef4f89-701a-447a-9375-3880115eb65a and
http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/11/applying-namespace-during-jaxb-unmarshal.html .

Finally, note that to annotate XML elements with type info, there's the established convention to use the `xsi:type` attribute so you might want to embrace it and change your design rather than invent your own mapping rules.